# Converting BigInteger to binary string

Tags: java, biginteger

Can we convert Biginteger to binary string

```
   String s1 = "0011111111101111111111111100101101111100110000001011111000010100";
   String s2 = "0011111111100000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100";
   BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;
   bi1 = new BigInteger(s1,2);
   bi2 = new BigInteger(s2,2);
   bi3 = bi1.xor(bi2);
```

How to convert bi3 to binary string

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`toString(radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) for that:

```
String s3 = bi3.toString(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Number: ");
    String n = in.next();
    BigInteger nn = new BigInteger(n);
    if(nn.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)<0){
        System.out.println("Number cannot be less than 0");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Convert to binary is:");
        print2Binaryform(nn);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
private static void print2Binaryform(BigInteger number) {
    BigInteger reminder2;
    if(number.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)<=0){
        System.out.print(number);
        return;
    }
    reminder2 = number.mod(new BigInteger(""+2));
    print2Binaryform(new BigInteger(""+number.divide(new BigInteger("2"))));
    System.out.print(reminder2);
}
```

Comment: Hi Riven. In what way do you think your answer is better than the one dasblinkenlight posted? (His answer is a one-liner: `nn.toString(2);`)

Comment: Oh, honestly, my code is too much larger, but i think it represents the logic better and it could be implemented in more ways by customizing it.

Comment: for example, you could change to conver decimal to base-n

Comment: Hi again Riven. That is what the `BigInteger.toString( int radix )` method is for, exactly for converting to base-n (n being the radix).